# License key system for OS X apps

Tags: macos

What are OS X developers using for a license key system on OS X apps not sold through the Mac App Store?  Is there a third party selling a toolkit to do this kind of thing?  My Google searches have so far not been productive.

Answer (score 0):

I am not OS X developer, but I am guessing they are using some licensing systems developed by themselves.